# Jquery validation for different type of date format

Tags: jquery, date

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2q9T/

I am trying to validate input using jQuery supporting different types of date formats (formats accepted are `mm/dd/yyyy` or `mm-dd-yyyy` or `mm.dd.yyyy`)

```
  ^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:0?2(\/|-|\.)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

but this does not work.. can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `filter` as regular expression for it be able to perform `.test()`

EDIT: replace the double quotations `"` with slashe `/` for it to validate the expression:

The following modified version of your code works. Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2q9T/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.validate-date').change(function (e) {
        var valid_date = $(this).val();
        var filter = new RegExp(/^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:0?2(\/|-|\.)29\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/);

      if(filter.test(valid_date))

       alert("Date");

           else

           alert("Not date"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: @Parvathiiiii I did not change the regular expression. I just used the one you have written. If you need to validate other formats, you will need to look for another regualr expression and plug it instead of the one you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this for your given patterns/Formats  mm/dd/yyyy or mm-dd-yyyy or mm.dd.yyyy

```
$('.validate-date').change(function (e) {
            var valid_date = $(this).val();

            var filter_month1 = /^\d{2},{11},{12}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}$/;
            var filter_month2 = /^\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4}$/;
            var filter_month3 = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;

            var month1 = valid_date.split("/")[0];
            var month2 = valid_date.split(".")[0];
            var month3 = valid_date.split("-")[0];
            if (month1 >= 13 || month2 >= 13 || month3 >= 13) {
                alert("Not date");
            } else {
                if (filter_month1.test(valid_date) || filter_month2.test(valid_date) || filter_month3.test(valid_date)) {
                    alert("Date");
                }
                else {

                    alert("Not date");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: i have tested this in fiddle it working on all formats that you mention.

Comment: Try  this 
var filter_month1 = new RegExp(/\b\d{1,2}[\./-]\d{1,2}[\./-]\d{4}\b/);

Comment: Please check now the edited code. may be its wrong way to do,but i m trying my best ,when i get good way i will post that code also.Thanks